# Cakephp 3 Append $this->request->data using array() - Indirect modification of overloaded property data has no effect

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I have been trying and trying a lot but i just don't understand how to achieve this .. Here is what i want to achieve by the way..

I am using cakephp 3.0 and i am trying to append `$this->request->data` by trying below code in my controller...

```
$this->data['Leaveregisters'] = array(
                                'name'=>'another',
                                'surname'=>'whatever'
                                );
echo '<pre>';
print_r($this->request->data);
exit;
```

but i am keep getting below error

> Notice (8): Indirect modification of overloaded property App\Controller\LeaveregistersController::$data has no effect

However, i am able to append data using below code

```
$this->request->data['name'] = 'another';
$this->request->data['surname'] = 'whatever';
```

But i am just wondering why i am not able to achieve the same thing using `array()` or what should i do to achieve this ?

Array should be appened in the same array as well if i do `$this->request->data` currently if i use below code

```
$this->request->data('Leaveregisters', [
    'name' => 'another',
    'surname' => 'whatever asdfa'
]);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($this->request->data);
exit;
```

Its getting appeneded but with new key like below which i do not want

```
Array
(
    [leaveregister_user_id] => 2
    [leaveregister_num_leaves] => 15
    [leaveregister_sdate] => 2016-09-01
    [leaveregister_edate] => 2016-09-22
    [leaveregister_leave_type] => 1
    [leaveregister_status] => 1
    [leaveregister_created_date] => 2016-09-20 14:54:29
    [leaveregister_modified_date] => 2016-09-20 14:54:29
    [Leaveregisters] => Array
        (
            [name] => another
            [surname] => whatever asdfa
        )

)
```

I want something like this instead...

```
  Array
    (
        [leaveregister_user_id] => 2
        [leaveregister_num_leaves] => 15
        [leaveregister_sdate] => 2016-09-01
        [leaveregister_edate] => 2016-09-22
        [leaveregister_leave_type] => 1
        [leaveregister_status] => 1
        [leaveregister_created_date] => 2016-09-20 14:54:29
        [leaveregister_modified_date] => 2016-09-20 14:54:29        
        [name] => another
        [surname] => whatever asdfa


    )
```

So that i can just save my data using `$this->request->data`
Can someone guide me for the same ?

Thanks

Comment: If you don't want that key, then why you use the key as an example? What exactly should the final data look like?

Comment: i simply want those 2 new values in the same array instead of new key altogether because below i am just saving the data using **$this->request->data**.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `Controller::$data` property anymore in CakePHP 3.

**[Cookbook > Appendices > 3.X Migration Guide > 3.0 Migration Guide > Controller](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-0-migration-guide.html#id2)**

The only correct way is to access the request object, and of course you can set nested data if you want to the same way, ie:

```
$this->request->data['Leaveregisters'] = [
    'name' => 'another',
    'surname' => 'whatever'
];
```

Alternatively use the `data()` method:

```
$this->request->data('Leaveregisters', [
    'name' => 'another',
    'surname' => 'whatever'
]);
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Request & Response Objects > Request Body Data](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#request-body-data)**
- **[API > \Cake\Network\Request::data()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.3/class-Cake.Network.Request.html#_data)**

Comment: Please don't come up with new requirements in the comments, if there is more to your problem, then you should add that to your question where you can explain it in proper detail. Also please never post such huge code fragements in a comments, it's highly unreadable - thanks! Also make sure that you read the linked docs. @MittulAtTechnoBrave